# jQuery | Add/Remove Class on Click | Best Practise

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

today I had to set a number of images as a galery. 
On the mobile version of this site I had to stack the images because it wasn´t possible to show them in a row of 4 or something.

Yet the images were quite high (350px) for a mobile view so I´ve decided to shrink them down to a height of 100px and make them clickable to extend to their full height.

I did this just by adding or removing a class called "extended" which would set the height to 350px again.

The JavaScript I used for this works but yet I´m not sure if this is what you would call best practise or if it could be done easier:

```
$('.galery__img--fragrance').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('extended')) {
      $(this).removeClass('extended');
    } else {
      $(this).parent().find('.extended').removeClass('extended');
      $(this).addClass('extended');
    }
  });
```

I hope this question isn´t to redundant but I´m quite new to JS/jQuery and I want to do it right :-)

Edit: Maybe I should´ve mentioned that I wanted to make images collapse to a height of 100px if they were clicked again or if another image was clicked

Comment: use  $( this ).toggleClass( ".extended" );

Answer (score 2):

Use `.toggleClass()` function to add/remove class simultanuously:

```
$('.galery__img--fragrance').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('extended');
});
```

Comment: Hey Jayesh, that was my first intention too but I wanted other images to collapse to a height of 100px again if they were clicked again or if another image was clicked so this wouldn´t work

Comment: Add `('.galery__img--fragrance').removeClass('extended')` to remove it from all other images before the toggle?